# How to display html table looping through multiple rows read from a file

Tags: html, json

I am trying to display the json response into a html table. One of the fields is an image that I want to be shown in the table. My current code just displays the last key/value from the json response, instead of all in the table.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.tutorialspoint.com/scripts/style.css" />
<script type="application/javascript">
function loadJSON()
{
   var http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
   var data_file = "/vcaWS/api/sources";

   http_request.onreadystatechange  = function(){
      if (http_request.readyState == 4  )
      {
        // Javascript function JSON.parse to parse JSON data
        var jsonObj = JSON.parse(http_request.responseText);

        for(var i=0;i<jsonObj.length;i++){
            document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = jsonObj[i].title;
            document.getElementById("logo_sm").innerHTML = jsonObj[i].logo_sm;
        }
    }
   }
   http_request.open("GET", data_file, true);
   http_request.send();
}
</script>
<title>Test JSON</title>
</head>
<body style="width:960px">
<h1>Test JSON</h1>
<table class="src">
<tr><th>Title</th><th>Logo_Small</th></tr>
<tr>
<td><div id="title">Youtube</div></td>
<td><div id="logo_sm">Youtube</div></td>
</tr>
</table>
<div class="central">
<button type="button" onclick="loadJSON();">JSON Store </button>
</body>
</html>
```

The json response is as below:

```
[
   {
      "title":"Virtual Magician s Video Podcast",
      "logo_sm":"http://a5.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Podcasts/v4/cf/53/e1/cf53e162-f4c7-7842-173d-7f7f2a79fd7e/mza_854261567010408552.100x100-75.jpg"
   },
   {
      "title":"shralp! //surfing video podcast//",
      "logo_sm":"http://a5.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Podcasts/v4/ea/ff/d0/eaffd0d3-b1f9-e886-2ffd-5ff14bcb5edb/mza_1030973830906343038.100x100-75.jpg"
   },
   {
      "title":"this WEEK in TECH Video (small)",
      "logo_sm":"http://a4.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Podcasts2/v4/fb/59/fc/fb59fc2d-b1a2-98cf-e1f8-32bae7217912/mza_5512264877031055372.100x100-75.jpg"
   }
]
```

Also, I was hoping to show the jpg file as an image. Currently, its a text value shown in the html table.

Comment: Do you want to add to the table, or completely replace the table contents?

Comment: I want to add it to the table. Basically, trying to have it in the format Title      Logo_sm with 3 rows underneath

Comment: There will be 4 rows: the 1 row in the original HTML, plus the 3 rows from the JSON. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating through the JSON object but on each iteration you are replacing the innerHTML of the rows with the ith object. 
Therefore it will only show the last item of the JSON object. 
Just get the table and insert a row for each item.

```
var mytable = document.getElementById("tableid");
for(var i=0;i<jsonObj.length;i++){

    var myrow = mytable.insertRow(0);
    var mytitlecell = myrow.insertCell(0);
    var mylogocell = myrow.insertCell(1);
    mytitlecell.innerHTML = jsonObj[i].title;
    mylogocell.innerHTML = "<img src='"+jsonObj[i].logo_sm+"'/>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will add the JSON data as new rows in the table.

```
var rows = '';
for(var i=0;i<jsonObj.length;i++){
    rows += '<tr><td class="title">' + jsonObj[i].title + '</td><td class="logo_sm">' + jsonObj[i].logo_sm + '</td></tr>';
}
document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].innerHTML += rows;
```

Comment: Thanks...It nows fetches data as expected... Can I display logo_sm which is a link to an image to directly show that image in the table ?

Comment: You can do anything that can be expressed in HTML.